# $P$ projector. prove that $\langle Px,x\rangle=\|Px\|^2.$

Tags: operator-theory

Let $X$ be a Hilbert space and $P \in B(X)$ a projector. Then for any $x\in X$:

$$\langle Px,x\rangle=\|Px\|^2.$$

My proof:

$$\|Px\|^{2}=\langle Px,Px\rangle=\langle P^{*}Px,x\rangle=\langle P^2x,x\rangle=\langle Px,x\rangle.$$

Is ok ? Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, seems ok. Is self-adjointness included in the definition of projector?

Comment: yes :) $P$ is a projector if $P^2=P$ and $P^{*}=P.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is all.
$$ \quad \quad $$